# contract name throws undefined error?

Tags: javascript, blockchain, ethereum, solidity, truffle

```
  Mortgage.new({ from: ownerAccount, gas: defaultGas }).then(
    function(loanInstance) {
        loanContractAddress = loanInstance.address;
        $('#sectionAAddress').html('<i class="fa fa-address-card"></i> ' +
```

Mortgage is the contract name

```
var Mortgage = artifacts.require("./Mortgage.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Mortgage);
};
```

Mortgage.sol

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.4;

contract Mortgage {

  function Mortgage()
  {
    loanApplicant = msg.sender;
    loan.status = STATUS_INITIATED;
    balances[msg.sender] = 100000000;
  }

  /* address of the loan applicant */
  address loanApplicant;
```

I get the below js error in 
UI

> Uncaught ReferenceError: Mortgage is not defined
>       at deployLoanContract (app.js:22316)
>       at HTMLButtonElement. (app.js:22610)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.dispatch (jquery.min.js:3)
>       at HTMLButtonElement.r.handle (jquery.min.js:3) deployLoanContract @ app.js:22316 (anonymous) @ app.js:22610 dispatch @ jquery.min.js:3
>   r.handle @ jquery.min.js:3

Please find the github url below to check the whole code
https://github.com/rajivjc/mortgage-blockchain-demo/issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

issue reoslved by deleting the build folder and did build  again

Comment: I did have same error and tried your suggestion, but didn't work. Looks like some people commented same on the Medium post as well. Any other suggestion for this problem?